# Redirecting command output in docker

Tags: linux, bash, logging, redirection, docker

I want to do some simple logging for my server which is a small Flask app running in a Docker container.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM dreen/flask
MAINTAINER dreen
WORKDIR /srv

# Get source
RUN mkdir -p /srv
COPY perfektimprezy.tar.gz /srv/perfektimprezy.tar.gz
RUN tar x -f perfektimprezy.tar.gz
RUN rm perfektimprezy.tar.gz

# Run server
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "index.py", "1>server.log", "2>server.log"]
```

As you can see on the last line I redirect stderr and stdout to a file. Now I run this container and shell into it

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 perfektimprezy
docker exec -it "... id of container ..." bash
```

And observe the following things:

The server is running and the website working

There is no `/srv/server.log`

`ps aux | grep python` yields:

```
root         1  1.6  3.2  54172 16240 ?        Ss   13:43   0:00 python index.py 1>server.log 2>server.log
root        12  1.9  3.3 130388 16740 ?        Sl   13:43   0:00 /usr/bin/python index.py 1>server.log 2>server.log
root        32  0.0  0.0   8860   388 ?        R+   13:43   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

But there are no logs... HOWEVER, if I `docker attach` to the container I can see the app generating output in the console.

How do I properly redirect stdout/err to a file when using Docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to question your use-case.  Why do you need to redirect stderr/stdout to a log file in the container?  Merged stderr and stdout are available outside the container using "docker logs", and they can be redirected to a file (outside of the container.)  More details can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/afolarin/a2ac14231d9079920864)

Comment: youre right, it seems i can even do `docker logs ID > stdout.log 2>stdout.log` but i still cant see an exception... im starting to think it might be dying without an error

Comment: Here's a use case: you're running the container on Docker Cloud (where you can't just redirect the log output to a file on the (remote and not easily accessible) node. You run a lot of different headless containers and you want to collect the respective outputs (possibly gigabytes of data) a few hours later.

Comment: @hheimbuerger  "Why do you need to redirect stderr/stdout to a log file in the container?"  Even with your use case description, I would question the use of logging *INSIDE* a container.  If you need log/event messages from headless containers, I think it would be easier to use tools that enable those files/messages to be viewed/stored outside of the container.  Perhaps using a [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) that meets your needs might be a better choice than logging inside of a container.

Comment: ` docker events &
echo copy paste an event id
docker logs <<event-id>> `

Answer (score 2):

Here's some info on a related use case: *You want to redirect the output inside the container, which is running on Docker Cloud.*

In my case, I'm executing a long-running data analysis script (Java) on Docker Cloud. Each container is supposed to write its own results file. I'm using the `java:8-jre` image and overwrite the 'Run command' with the following line:

```
bash -c "java -jar /code/analyzer.jar > /data/results-$RANDOM.txt"
```

By using bash's `$RANDOM` variable, I can scale up the number of containers in Docker Cloud as much as I want, while still collecting the results individually.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for tee

```
LOGFILE="logthis.txt";
IMG_alpine="alpine:3.5";

docker run --rm \
--name alpine-hello \
--hostname alpine-hello \
"$IMG_alpine" \
uname -a | tee -a $LOGFILE

cat logthis.txt
Linux alpine-hello 4.8.14-docker-2 #1 SMP Tue Jan 10 15:35:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `docker run` in a shell pipeline or under shell redirection, making `run` accept stdin and output to stdout and stderr appropriately, use this incantation:

```
docker run -i --log-driver=none -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr ...
```

e.g. to run the `alpine` image and execute the UNIX command `cat` in the contained environment:

```
echo "This was piped into docker" |
  docker run -i --log-driver=none -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr \
    alpine cat - |
  xargs echo This is coming out of docker:
```

emits:

```
This is coming out of docker: This was piped into docker
```